# Using Hardware Security Modules to generate and store private keys on private ethereum / quorum

Tags: security

For a private ethereum networks, has anyone used Hardware Security Modules (HSM) to generate and store Ethereum private keys?

I am keen to know how public/private keys are managed without a PKI (Public Key Infrastructure)

Answer (score 1):

This feature is now being considered as an enhancement in Quorum.

https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum/issues/459